# Show that $c(t)=\left(f(t),t^2\right)$ lies along the graph of $h(x)=|x|$. Unclear answer book.

Tags: functions, parametric

Calculus by michael spivak (3rd edition) chapter 12 (apendix) question 2 goes as follows

> Let 
>   $$f(t)=
> \begin{cases}
> t^2&,x\geq0\\
> -t^2&,x\leq0
> \end{cases}$$
>   Show that $c(t)=\left(f(t),t^2\right)$ lies along the graph of $h(x)=|x|$.

The answer book states

> We have 
>   $$f(t)=
> \begin{cases}
> t^2&,x\geq0\\
> -t^2&,x\leq0
> \end{cases}$$
>   and these points are all on the graph of $h(x)=|x|$, since $|-t^2|=t^2$.

to me, these seems to be a pointles answer.

What is the actual reason $c$ lies along the graph of $h$? In other words, how could one know that it does?

Comment: This is Spivak. Hundreds of thousands of students over decades have relied on this book. The answer book cannot be pointless.

Comment: I agree. It is often very, very useful. I'm refering to specific answer (given by the answer book) in question.

Comment: _None_ of the answers in the book can be pointless.

Comment: The point is to show that there are different parameterisations of the same curve. Here $c$ is differentiable, but the curve $t \mapsto (t,h(t))$ is not.

Comment: The graph $G$ is just a set of points. It is not clear what you mean by reason. A point $(x,y)$ lies on the graph **iff** $(x,y) \in G$.

Comment: I guess my question would be, how could one know that $c$ lies in $h$? How could I tell if it didn´t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the graph of $h$ is the set $G = \{(x,|x|) :\, x \in \mathbb R\}$. A point in $G$ is of the form $(x,x)$ or $(x,-x)$, right? The points,
$$(-2,2),(0,0),(-1,1),(\pi,\pi),(-\sin 1,\sin 1)$$
are point that lies in $G$ to be clear. Now, since $c(t)$ is either $(t^2,t^2)$ or $(-t^2,t^2)$, clearly lies in $G$. Are you more convinced?

To be formal, a point $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ lies in $G$ if and only if $y=|x|$, that is, an ordered pair lies in $G$ if and only if their second entry is the absolute value of the first. So, in the case that $c(t) = (t^2,t^2)$ it is obvoius that $c(t) \in G$, and in the other case, the case that $c(t) = (-t^2,t^2)$, $c(t) \in G$ since $|-t^2| = t^2$.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. One thing though, wouldn't $G = \{(x,|x|) :\, x \in \mathbb R\}$ consist of only point whose second coordinate is a positive number (meaning $(2,-2)\notin G$)? I'm guessing It's a typo. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for telling me my mistake.